# API call from AWS failing

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, dotnet-httpclient

I have a lambda that makes an API call via HTTP Client. When running locally it works fine.

I have deployed to AWS in a lambda and the call just hangs until the lambda times out. I tried a call to another URL and it works fine.

Why would it work fine on my local machine but fail on AWS?

Comment: Is your lambda ain VPC?

Comment: no it does not use a VPC. Internet connection is fine.

Comment: Maybe the external API blocks AWS ip ranges? Have you checked if you can call the API from an instance, for example?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by an instance?

Comment: EC2 instance. The reason is to make sure this is only a lambda issue, not AWS as a whole.

Comment: I also assume that lambda has enough time, and its not lambda execution timeout (default is 3 seconds)?

Comment: Increase the timeout to maximum for debugging so it will at least clear one thing that issue is with lambda or the API, as it work for other url it might be possible that the response time of time other url is less then the execution time out so that's why it's working